# Display text alongside images in the same line?

Tags: html, css, image, css-float

I want to have text to the left of images and in the same line.

How do I do that?

**HTML :**

```
<p class="steps">some text</p>
<img class="images"src="images/1.png" width="800">

<p class="steps">some text</p>
<img class="images"src="images/2.png" width="800">

<p class="steps">some text</p>
<img class="images"src="images/3.png" width="800">
```

**CSS:**

```
  .images
    {
    float : right;
    }

    .steps
    {
    float : left;

    }
```

But this isn't doing it.

I'm getting image after text but not side by side.I also want to have the text at half the height of the image.

How do I do this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

`<p>` is a block element, which forces a line break before and after it. Changing it's display to `inline` or `inline-block` will do.

```
p{
 display:inline;
}
```

In your case

```
.steps
{
 float : left;
 display:inline;
}
```

Comment: No still I find the image only after text but it is to right as it should be.

Comment: You want the text after image? if so, simply out the `<p>` `<img>`

Comment: @nikki isn't it currently on the left?

Answer (score 1):

```
<section>
    <figure>
        <img class=images src=https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYZ6I.png/>
        <figcaption class=steps>some text</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure>
        <img class=images src=https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYZ6I.png/>
        <figcaption class=steps>some text</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure>
        <img class=images src=https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYZ6I.png/>
        <figcaption class=steps>some text</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure>
        <img class=images src=https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYZ6I.png/>
        <figcaption class=steps>some text</figcaption>
    </figure>        
</section>
```

css:

```
*{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

figure{
    width:25%;
    float:left;/*you need this*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need some restructure in your HTML. Here is your answer and DEMO

```
.steps {
   float: left;
   padding:0px 10px;
   vertical-align:middle;
}
.steps img{
   display:inline;
   vertical-align:middle;
}
```

[***DEMO***](http://cssdesk.com/PsrTH)